# std::vector: vec.data() or &vec[0]

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

When you want access a std::vector as a C array you can choose from at least four different ways, as you can see in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  vec.push_back(1);
  vec.push_back(2);
  vec.push_back(42);
  vec.push_back(24024);
  {
    int* arr = vec.data();
    cout << arr << endl; /* output: 0x9bca028 */
    cout << arr[3] << endl; /* output : 24024 */
  }
  {
    int* arr = &vec.front();
    cout << arr << endl; /* output: 0x9bca028 */
    cout << arr[3] << endl; /* output : 24024 */
  }
  {
    int* arr = &vec[0];
    cout << arr << endl; /* output: 0x9bca028 */
    cout << arr[3] << endl; /* output : 24024 */
  }
  {
    int* arr = &vec.at(0);
    cout << arr << endl; /* output: 0x9bca028 */
    cout << arr[3] << endl; /* output : 24024 */
  }
}
```

The one I've found in most cases is the `&vec[0]`. I think it's the least elegant, so... why is it the most used? Is it **more efficient** or **more compatible**? I can't find lot of documentation about `data()`.

Comment: `data()` *may* be regarded incompatible in the sense that it's C++11 (which explains the scarce documentation, as major documentation sources are just catching up with new features), though time will surely make this incompatibility vanish and then it's the definite way to go.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`data()` is brand new to C++11, that's why you don't see it as often.  The idea of using `&vec.front()` never even occurred to me, probably because I use `operator[]` alot more often than `front()` (almost never).  I imagine it's the same for other people.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Only for const vectors, [I think](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).  I'll test it now.

Comment: @MooingDuck No. It was added exactly so people wouldn't have to write: `v.empty()?NULL:&v[0]`.

Comment: @MooingDuck my example compiles and runs, and as you can see data() returns a non const pointer.

Comment: So `data()` is not compatible with old C++?

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato: Correct, though I'm having a hard time proving it, as GCC appears to support it even when not in C++11 mode.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm using gcc 4.4 with standard C++ and `data()` works fine.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato: Yeah, that's why I said I'm having a hard time proving it.  It may have been an early adopted extension.  I don't have a C++03 official standard on hand.  But I can refer to old, semi-reliable sources where `data()` doesn't appear, like [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) ,or [this book.](http://www.amazon.com/The-Complete-Reference-4th-Edition/dp/0072226803/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1337873363&sr=8-1)

Comment: `data()` has been a non-standard extention to vector in libstdc++ for a while.  Now it's part of the standard as of C++11

Answer (score 24):

If you're using C++11, then using `data()` is definitely preferable.  In particular, if the vector is empty, then using either of the other two options yields undefined behavior!  If you're not using C++11, and the vector may be empty, then be sure to check that condition.

Answer (score 6):

Using &vec[0] is the most common although, I agree, does look a little odd. One thing to keep in mind for the future. If your vector happens to be a vector of objects whose class overloads the operator&(), realize that this will cause strange behavior if you call &vec[0].

This will not get the starting address of the first item in the internal contiguous array of objects, it will return whatever vec[0].operator&() would return. Most if not all of the time, that's not the address you're looking for (Jedi hand wave).

A good example of this is ATL's CComPtr. It overloads operator&() so storing it in a vector can be problematic. To get around this, ATL has a CAdapt template class which can be used to hide the operator&() on CComPtr

Answer (score 1):

Before C++11's `std::array` I would say that `std::vector` was the most common container to be used instead of the C-style array. The `[]` operator usually implies constant time access, (which is what `std::vector` is all about), and so most coders usually choose this style to reflect array-like access and behavior.

Answer (score 1):

data() has been part of `std::string` for some time now so you might read-up on that. I've found the data() implementation in `std::vector` to be similar. I occasionally use data() to treat a `std::string` as an array of raw bytes.