# Is vector.data() not null after vector.reserve()?

Tags: c++

[`vec.data()` usually is `&vec[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740094/stdvector-vec-data-or-vec0) except when `vec.empty()` . In the latter case, `vec.data()` might be a `nullptr`.

Question: If I call `vec.reserve` with a sufficient size, I know that `&vec[0]` won't change anymore. But for the edge case of an initially-empty vector, can I rely on `vec.data()` being stable as well?

Rationale: in a ctor I want to initialize a `const T* const` to `vec.data()`. None of the class members will let `vec` grow past the reserved size. I *could* add a temporary single element just so I could write `&vec[0]`, but that seems a bit contrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My take on this that no, empty vector does not guarantee that `vector::data` returns the underlying buffer even after a call to `vector::reserve`.**

## Reasoning

AFAIK `vector::data()` was proposed in [issue n. 464](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue464) and it looks like that the exact same proposed wording was accepted into the Standard.

Excerpt from the discussion:

> To add slightly more convenience to vector and map<Key,T> we should
> consider to add
>
> 1. add vector::data() member (const and non-const version) semantics:
>    if( empty() ) return 0; else return buffer_;
> 2. ...
>
> Rationale:
>
> - To obtain a pointer to the vector's buffer, one must use either
>   operator (which can give undefined behavior for empty vectors) or
>   at() (which will then throw if the vector is empty).
>
> ...

[Standard draft - 22.3.11.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.data):

> Returns: A pointer such that [data(), data() + size()) is a valid
> range. For a non-empty vector, data() == addressof(front()).

It seems that the authors wanted in their rationale to always return `nullptr` for an empty container, which would be your case. But the proposed and accepted wording left that ambiguous.

**The bottom line is `vector::data()` for an empty vector still returns indeterminate value.**

Other parts of the Standard ([[22.3.11.3]](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.capacity)) together guarantee that the buffer will exist after call to reserve but `::data` still might return e.g. `nullptr` as per the original discussion.

## The safe way

The only safe way seem to be the your solution of:

1. Adding dummy element
2. Storing `vector::data()` return value as it is now guaranteed to be `&v[o]`.
3. Deleting the dummy element.

Note, 2.,3. cannot be exchanged, `data` could again start return anything.

I am not aware of any downsides resulting from the following wording which would resolve the situation.

> Returns: A pointer such that [data(), data() + size()) is a valid
> range. For a non-zero capacity vector, data() == addressof(front())
> had the vector had a size of at least 1 at the moment of the call.

Comment: this is really annoying since it is not the same for the allocation of an empty array : In "char* tab = new char[0];" tab is not nullptr, and in "std::vector<char> vec(0);", vec.data() is a nullptr !!

Comment: And i didn't found any method to return a non-nullptr from an empty vector.